# How to get the profile photo of facebook user who is registered my site with facebook registration application(not using mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-fql

I am developing a web page default.aspx.(Not an mvc application) with a facebook registration plugin.I need to get the profile picture of user who is logging into my application using their facebook id.I saw fql examples but i dont know how to implement it in c# code behind page. I was able to get the profile information in code behind.Please help me how to get the profile picture from user who is registering my page .i am using c# 2008

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting the FacebookID just generate the image URL

```
 <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/FacebookIDOrUserName/picture"/>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

If you need to download the image:

```
Image image = null;
string URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/FacebookIDOrUserName/picture";

HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
req.Timeout = 20000;

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

image = Image.FromStream(stream);

resp.Close();
```

Comment: I think i need to elaborate my question. I am using iframe vesion of facebook registration plugin and in the code behind page i am able to get the username(not id).How to configure the web.config for using fql c# application to get the profile picture?? Thanks for the reply and hope i submitted my qn neatly .

Comment: Is tha image object is of system.web.ui.webcontrol or system.drawing ?? pls help

Comment: @AntoAugustine - System.Drawing